# Density Function of Random Variable Related to Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

[image: Question]

Above is my question. I've done the first two parts, that's no problem. I'm stuck on finding the density of the rv $R = W_1 / M$. I have got as far as
$$g(x,y) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} \Bbb P(M \le x, W_1 \le y) = \frac{2(2x-y)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp \left(-\frac{1}{2}(2x - y)^2 \right)$$
for $x \ge y$ and $g(x,y) = 0$ for $x \le y$. I also have
$$ \Bbb P(R \ge r) = \Bbb P (W_1 \ge rM),$$
and so I'm now interested in evaluating a probability of the form "$\Bbb P(X \ge Y)$" for rvs $X = W_1$ and $Y = rM$. My attempt is then
$$\Bbb P(W_1 \le rM) = \int_{y < x} \frac{1}{r} g\left(\frac{x}{r},y\right) d(x,y),$$
where the $1/r$ factors come from the fact that $Y = rM$, not just $M$.

My issue is that this then gives $1$, for each $r$. So my density function is $1$ everywhere... which is of course not right (eg doesn't integrate to $1$). Of course, I only want to consider $r < 1$ as the probability is $0$ for $r > 1$, by definition of the two rvs. Also, I am concerned with the $1/r$ factors... when $r$ could be $0$.

Any advice would be most appreciated. Thanks.

PS - This is a probability question - not a finance question - so please don't suggest migrating it to quant.SE - thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong in your calulations.

Integration yields

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{P}(W_1 \leq r M) &= \frac{1}{r} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{y<x} \frac{2(2x/r-y)}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp \left(- \frac{1}{2} (2x/r-y)^2 \right) \, dy \, dx \\ &= \frac{1}{r} \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp \left(- \frac{(2x/r-x)^2}{2} \right) \, dx \\ &= \frac{1}{r} \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp \left( -\frac{x^2 (2/r-1)^2}{2} \right) \, dx\end{align*}$$

Using the identity $$\int_{[0,\infty)} \exp \left(- \frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \int \exp \left(- \frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2} \right) \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2},$$ we get

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{P}(W_1 \leq r M) = \frac{1}{r} \frac{1}{|2/r-1|} = \frac{1}{2-r} \tag{1} \end{align*}$$

for any $r \leq 1$, $r \neq 0$. Since

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \frac{W_1}{M} \leq 0 \right) = \mathbb{P}(W_1 \leq 0) = \frac{1}{2},$$

$(1)$ holds also for $r=0$. Differentiating $(1)$ with respect to $r$ gives the density of $W_1/M$.

Comment: Ah, see I was changing $x \to x/r$ in **both** the integrand and the limit, ie $y<x \to y<x/r$ and putting  the $1/r$ factor 'out front'. This was just equivalent to changing variables $x \to x/r$ in the integration, and since the density $g(x,y)$ was only non-zero up to $x < y$, then this was basically just the integral over everything, hence going to 1.
So basically where you have $(2/r - 1)^2$, I had $(2/r - 1/r)^2$, which was messing life up royally! Helpfully the form for $r = 0$ gives the same form. :)

Comment: Anyway, "manies graciaces", as people say who are neither good at English nor Spanish, but have a minor understanding of both (quite a niche crowd).